# cual es la utilidad de un raw String en kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

quiero saber que es exactamente lo que puede hacer un raw STring, que no puede hacer un String normal.
entendi como se usa gracias a esta pagina https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/string 
pero no queda muy claro cual es el objetivo de los raw String
**creo que es simplemente que los raw String pueden contener varias lineas de texto**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un detalle que parece que se te escapado es que no tienen caracteres escapados:

```
val texto= """ Esto es un "raw String" que muestra
\n \t sin problemas
Con saltos de línea sin usar \n """
```

Esto mostraría al imprimirlo en pantalla

```
Esto es un "raw String" que muestra
\n \t sin problemas
Con saltos de línea sin usar \n
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/6otcm6rshfu8r3ln3ghhdlo1ec/uit1lv9h3c48vjsd5sa0lu3aui)